# Babylon JS 3D File loading is not working

Tags: babylonjs

No Matter what type of file i try to import, i do not get it to show up in my Canvas.

What i have tried:

- Opening the files in 3D viewers, babylon sandbox and blender, there
  is nothing wrong with the models
- Scaling the Model up and down after importing it with the loaders
  (yeah, the importing is successful, no console errors and the
  onSuccess callback is called), since i thought it might just be way
  too big or too small for the camera to pick up.
- Different file formats (.babylon, .glb, .obj)
- all the different kind of SceneLoader functions, (Import Mesh, Append ...)

Here is my Code:

```
import { SceneLoader, Scene } from "babylonjs";
import "babylonjs-loaders";

const importFile = (
  path: string,
  fileName: string,
  ext: string,
  scene: Scene
) => {
  console.log(SceneLoader.IsPluginForExtensionAvailable(ext));
  SceneLoader.ImportMeshAsync("", path, fileName + ext, scene).then((meshes) =>

   // this actually does log some object with a bunch of fields, which dont seem to help me
 identify the problem. Maybe someone knows what kind of info that could give me.
    console.log(meshes)
 );
};


//specific Model being loaded
export const createChessBoard = (scene: Scene) => {
  importFile("/home/tom/Models/", "ChessBoard", ".obj", scene);
};
```

here it is being called

```
// the rest of the scene 
const scene = new Scene(engine);

  const camera = new ArcRotateCamera(
    "Camera",
    Math.PI / 2,
    Math.PI / 2,
    2,
    Vector3.Zero(),
    scene
  );
  if (canvas) {
    camera.attachControl(canvas, true);
  }

  const light1 = new HemisphericLight(
    "ambientlight",
    new Vector3(1, 1, 0),
    scene
  );
  const light2 = new PointLight("spotlight", new Vector3(0, 1, -1), scene);

  createChessBoard(scene);
```

Creating cameras,scenes and all that or shapes with the MeshBuilder works flawlessly. I couldnt find anyone having trouble with the loaders anywhere... Usually they are highly praised as working so effortlessly, i hope someone can help me resolve this, as babylon seems like such a cool library

Answer (score 0):

https://doc.babylonjs.com/api/classes/babylon.sceneloader#load

ImportMesh method(rather than ImportMeshAsync)  allows optional callbacks, like onError, onComplete etc.

These will be triggered when there is a problem or success etc, so that you can better debug the issue

function onError(e){
console.log(e) // hopefully some helpful info in e (might be e.message or e.error)

}

SceneLoader.ImportMesh("mesh1","./yourMeshFolder", onError);